# How to call javascript function on click of button in ribbon

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button in the ribbon. It has got ID.

I tried like

```
var mybtn= document.getElementById('btnId');
mybtn.onclick=myfun;


function myfun()
{
 ---------
 ---------
}
```

But it didnt work. Please suggest.

Comment: Please check mybtn is not null? If its, you must call the js after the button created. (e.g. body onload, or dom loaded)

Comment: First of all, you mean `function myfun()`, right?

Comment: Adding on to Burak TAMTURK's comment, check out the difference between  http://jsfiddle.net/xNybX/ and http://jsfiddle.net/xNybX/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
jQuery("#btnId").click(function(){

myfun();

});

function myfun()
{
    //Here is your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Simplest method is to add a mouse event `onclick="myfun()"` into element that has `id: "btnId"`
2. By using jQuery:

   `$("#btnId").click(function(){
           //do the code here
    });`